# getStaticProps returning undefined except I refresh my page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, supabase, getstaticprops

I'm having a problem in my nextjs app (13.0.5)

When navigating through the website, `product, seller and sellerProducts` are undefined except I refresh the page...

Ive tried fetching iit in the client with a useeffect, but I need this to work.

I have the same logic in other projects and they work fine...

I don't understand what is going on... Any help? Thanks!

dir: /product/[slug].tsx

```
const ProductPage = ({
  product,
  seller,
}: {
  product: Product;
  seller: Seller;
}) => {
  const { user, updateUser } = useUser();

  console.log(seller, product);

  if (!product || !seller) {
    return (
      <PageLayout>
          <p className="animate-pulse">Cargando...</p>
      </PageLayout>
    );
  }
  return (
    <PageLayout>
      <div className="contain flex flex-col">
        <ProductBody
          product={product}
          seller={seller}
          isActive={user.id === seller.id}
        />
      </div>
    </PageLayout>
  );
};

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  //logic here
  return { paths: allPaths, fallback: false };
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const productId = params?.slug;
  if (!productId) {
    return { props: { product: null, user: null } };
  }

  const { data: product, error } = await supabase
    .from("products")
    .select("seller, id, published_version, created_at, published")
    .eq("id", productId)
    .eq("published", true)
    .single();

  console.log("RESULTADOS", product, error);
  if (error || !product) {
    return { props: { product: null } };
  }

  if (!product || !product.seller) {
    return { notFound: true }; // Return notFound: true when the product doesn't exist
  }

  const { data: seller, error: sellerError } = await supabase
    .from("users")
    .select("*")
    .eq("id", product.seller)
    .single();

  if (sellerError || !seller) {
    return { notFound: true };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      product,
      seller,
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
};

export default ProductPage;
```

Comment: When you say `navigate through the website`, are you doing any client side routing? Because if yes, then `getStaticProps` wont be executed (since its on server). You can use `useEffect` or use Next.js `app` router for server components.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I mean, I’m using a nextjs <Link href={‘/product/${product.id}’}>See product</Link>.  Or what do you mean?

Comment: When you use `<Link>` component, it does a client side routing. Meaning that request do not reach the server (which is where the `getStaticProps` is executed) unless you refresh the page after the redirect.

Comment: Im using pages router and using that flow (navigating using Link components) and getStaticProps in other projects and works fine... 

In this project, altough the Next version is 13.0.5, I'm using pages router too.

Comment: I fixed it going back to 13.0.5